# Blending Methods for image Mosaic

Tags: java, image-processing

What is the Best method for blending two images into a single image? I have two tiff images, and i need to attach them and blend them. What algorithm would be beneficial for use???

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write anything, just use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

```
composite -dissolve 50% image1.tif image2.tif newimage.tif
```

Bindings are available for C, Perl, PHP, Python, Java etc.

Comment: I need to write the blending process as a code in java, rather than using a software.